# Why do I see the HttpResponseCode '200' when I have not even deployed the web-application?

Tags: java, http, jakarta-ee, http-response-codes

In my IDE only one web-project is opened and that is deployed on the *Tomcat Server*. But the following code tries to connect to a *web-app* that is neither open in the IDE nor is deployed by the *Tomcat*. But to my surprise,I always see the *if* statement running and printing *200* signifying *OK*. Is it that tomcat automatically deploys the *web-app* that hasn't been deployed ? If not,then what could be the reason ?

```
      final URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8084/other service/index.jsp");
      final HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
      int responseCode = urlc.getResponseCode();
      if(responseCode == 200){
          connected = true;
          System.out.println("Response code : " + responseCode);
      } else {
          System.out.println("Response code : " + responseCode);
        }
```

If i tamper with the *URL* and change it to something that is nonexistent,it gives a *404 code*. But,it should give a *404 code* when I have not deployed the *web-app* !

***Note:***

*I am using netbeans as an IDE.*

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to open `http://localhost:8084/other service/index.jsp` with a Web browser, it  will show what's going on.

Comment: I can see the page ! how is that ?

Comment: There's no way to know from here :)

Comment: well i am right here ! perhaps you can dictate/suggest me something http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20789/discussion-between-evgeniy-dorofeev-and-saplingpro :)